# Can a Qlik Sense table be set to default data plus whever selections get made on the sheet?

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I am fairly new to Qlik Sense, but am trying to create a table that will display a mix of vacant positions and positions that are selected from a bar chart. See, I have positions that are currently not vacant but in the future will be and are given a bucket value, like 2024-Qrt1. However, if the position is currently vacant, then the bucket value is "VACANT". I have a bar chart that shows the total number of positions by bucket value(but vacant positions are not displayed on the bar chart). I then have a table that displays the currently vacant positions but as a user selected the bars on the chart, I want the table to update to include the positions that are assigned those buckets plus VACANT.

I have tried the following: If(WildMatch(AllSort, '*$(=GerFieldSelections(CycleSort, ', ', ''',5))*'), AllSort) This works when I select one or more bars the and the table filter based on what was selected. However, I need to add the condition that AllSort = 'VACANT' in addition to what is selected on the bar chart. I just can't figure out how to keep the data in the table defaulted to VACANT and only displayed in addition to that VACANT data when one or more bars are selected. Is this even possible?